# Where to put a lock, close to the resource being used or up in the callstack near the client?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, locking

Where should I put a resource lock, close to the resource being shared or up in the call stack? What is the best practice?

For example:

```
class A
{
    private List<string> List = new List<string>();

    public void Add
    {
        this.list.Add("test");
    }
}
```

Should I lock inside the Add method or should I lock in the clients calling the Add method so only one is called each time?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I'm the owner of the calling code and the A class, with clients I mean higher layer calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to say; neither is inherently better.  It is going to depend on the specifics of what you need to do.

Is the caller ever going to need to call multiple methods and ensure they are all run "together" without anything else modifying the object while that's happening?  If someone needs to both check if an item exists and then add it if it doesn't, and you don't provide a single method to do that, then they'll *have* to do the locking from outside of the class.

If the caller knows that their critical sections will always be just one method, and that all access to the class needs to be in a critical section, then doing the locking inside of the class is both more convenient, and reduces the potential for errors.  Having the locks inside the class means that you don't need to worry about some usage not locking before access, or locking incorrectly, and corrupting an entirely different caller that is locking properly.  It also means that, if you have multiple callers, they need to provide some way of not only having a shared reference to the object, but also having some shared key to lock on.

If the object isn't always going to be accessed from multiple threads then you're also adding a fair amount of overhead locking on all access internally.  Being able to omit all locking because only a single thread accesses the object can be a noticeable performance difference, depending on usage.

There can be issues, depending on what your methods are doing, in which one of the methods is calling out to external code that is also locking on some other resource; if you're not very careful about how the class is coded and used, this can result in very obscure deadlocking errors.

And this is just a start of the considerations to make; this is most certainly not an exhaustive list of issues that either solution can have.  Welcome to the world of multithreading.

You simply need to make the decision based on the specific case of the type that you're dealing with.  There is no one answer that always applies.

Comment: the question rose because I was considering this and then I realized that no class on the .Net framework is thread safe so they always prefer to do the locking on the client code ... nice answer, +1.

Answer (score 1):

In general you want to lock as late as possible and keep the lock for as short a time as possible.

Lock as late as possible - release as early as possible.

Comment: Sounds as a good approach but then the question is why Microsoft does not use it in the Framework classes?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the features of the A class:

- if it must be thread-safe then take a lock each time
- if thread-safety is the responsibility of the user then do nothing

Note that making it thread safe using the C# lock construct, i.e. a monitor, should not be too costly in non concurrent scenarios.

And of course, whatever your choice, clearly document the class behavior.

Comment: Thread-safety or not is my own choice as I'm the owner of the class being used and the client code too ... anyway good to remember documenting the behaviour. +1

Answer (score 0):

To make `A` thread safe, you should of course lock in `A.Add`. A lock should be as close to the locked resource as possible. Also, the lock should be kept for as little time as possible.

Comment: Sounds as a good approach but then the question is why Microsoft does not use it in the Framework classes?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on the client to remember to lock every time. Also if you put it in your Add method it will avoid duplication

Comment: Looks like this is what the .Net framework forces you to do with their framework so probably there are good reasons to follow that path ...

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, clients cannot lock the list. But if you implement it as public they could. Anyways, if you lock the list, it doesn't matter if clients lock it or you do it within the `Add` method. It will be locked for all threads anyways.

So The only good place is within the Add method, to not copy&paste code and possibly implement errors in many places